# proof of a vector related expression

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have encountered a vector expression in the following way in a book.

$(\vec A+\vec B)^*=\vec A^*+\vec B^*$

Where, $\vec X^*$ represents the projection of the vector $\vec X$ in a given plane.I do not know how to prove the above vector expression.Can anyone suggest me as to how the above expression can be proved?

Answer (score 0):

Projections on subspaces are linear maps and one of the properties of linear maps $P$ is that $P(v+w)=P(v)+P(w)$.